# Reindexing a data frame in Pandas with a tolerance on new / old indicies

Tags: python, pandas

This is a bit of a follow up to a previous question ([Patch over missing rows in CSV file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622526/patch-over-missing-rows-in-csv-file-in-python))

The answer given before works well when the data increases normally, but some new data looks more like this:

```
time,a,b,c,d,e
"2016-12-28 00:00:01","4","2","2","8","0"
"2016-12-28 00:01:01","4","2","2","8","0"
"2016-12-28 00:02:01","4","2","2","8","0"
"2016-12-28 00:03:01","4","2","2","8","0"
"2016-12-28 00:05:01","4","2","2","8","0"
"2016-12-28 00:06:01","4","2","2","8","0"
"2016-12-28 00:07:01","4","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:08:01","4","2","2","7","0"
"2016-12-28 00:09:02","4","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:10:02","4","2","2","7","0"
"2016-12-28 00:11:02","3","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:12:05","3","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:13:02","3","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:18:02","3","2","2","7","0"
"2016-12-28 00:19:05","3","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:20:02","3","2","2","7","0"
"2016-12-28 00:21:02","3","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:22:03","3","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:23:02","3","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:24:02","3","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:25:05","3","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:26:02","3","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:27:03","3","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:28:01","3","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:29:02","3","2","1","7","1"
"2016-12-28 00:30:06","3","2","1","7","1"
```

Using the solution given before produces this result - it wipes out existing data when the index isn't a perfect match.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import datetime
z = pd.read_csv('smalldata.csv')
z = z[~z.time.duplicated()]
z['time'] = pd.to_datetime(z['time'])
x = z.set_index('time').reindex(pd.date_range(min(z['time']),max(z['time']),freq="1min"))

print(x)
```

output

```
2016-12-28 00:00:01  4.0  2.0  2.0  8.0  0.0
2016-12-28 00:01:01  4.0  2.0  2.0  8.0  0.0
2016-12-28 00:02:01  4.0  2.0  2.0  8.0  0.0
2016-12-28 00:03:01  4.0  2.0  2.0  8.0  0.0
2016-12-28 00:04:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:05:01  4.0  2.0  2.0  8.0  0.0
2016-12-28 00:06:01  4.0  2.0  2.0  8.0  0.0
2016-12-28 00:07:01  4.0  2.0  1.0  7.0  1.0
2016-12-28 00:08:01  4.0  2.0  2.0  7.0  0.0
2016-12-28 00:09:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:10:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:11:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:12:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:13:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:14:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:15:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:16:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:17:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:18:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:19:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:20:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:21:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:22:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:23:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:24:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:25:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:26:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:27:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:28:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:29:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-12-28 00:30:01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I can ffill() this, but I'll just get the last valid value copied down forever, rather then just filling in the missing minutes as I really want.

I've tried setting the reindex freq to cover the range the seconds part of the time stamp varies in, but with no success. I've also looked at the tolerance option, but can't really find any documentation on it, and my experiments with it have not proved useful.

Is there anyway to reindex the dataframe when the index isn't monotonically incrementing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***solution 1***
use `asfreq`

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df = df.set_index('time')
df.asfreq('min', 'nearest')

                     a  b  c  d  e
time                              
2016-12-28 00:00:01  4  2  2  8  0
2016-12-28 00:01:01  4  2  2  8  0
2016-12-28 00:02:01  4  2  2  8  0
2016-12-28 00:03:01  4  2  2  8  0
2016-12-28 00:04:01  4  2  2  8  0
2016-12-28 00:05:01  4  2  2  8  0
2016-12-28 00:06:01  4  2  2  8  0
2016-12-28 00:07:01  4  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:08:01  4  2  2  7  0
2016-12-28 00:09:01  4  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:10:01  4  2  2  7  0
2016-12-28 00:11:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:12:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:13:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:14:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:15:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:16:01  3  2  2  7  0
2016-12-28 00:17:01  3  2  2  7  0
2016-12-28 00:18:01  3  2  2  7  0
2016-12-28 00:19:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:20:01  3  2  2  7  0
2016-12-28 00:21:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:22:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:23:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:24:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:25:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:26:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:27:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:28:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:29:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:30:01  3  2  1  7  1
```

***solution 2***
use `reindex` with `'nearest'` and `tolerance`

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df = df.set_index('time')
tidx = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='min')
df.reindex(tidx, method='nearest', tolerance='5min')

                     a  b  c  d  e
2016-12-28 00:00:01  4  2  2  8  0
2016-12-28 00:01:01  4  2  2  8  0
2016-12-28 00:02:01  4  2  2  8  0
2016-12-28 00:03:01  4  2  2  8  0
2016-12-28 00:04:01  4  2  2  8  0
2016-12-28 00:05:01  4  2  2  8  0
2016-12-28 00:06:01  4  2  2  8  0
2016-12-28 00:07:01  4  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:08:01  4  2  2  7  0
2016-12-28 00:09:01  4  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:10:01  4  2  2  7  0
2016-12-28 00:11:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:12:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:13:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:14:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:15:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:16:01  3  2  2  7  0
2016-12-28 00:17:01  3  2  2  7  0
2016-12-28 00:18:01  3  2  2  7  0
2016-12-28 00:19:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:20:01  3  2  2  7  0
2016-12-28 00:21:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:22:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:23:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:24:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:25:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:26:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:27:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:28:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:29:01  3  2  1  7  1
2016-12-28 00:30:01  3  2  1  7  1
```